# calling jquery confirm box on cs file of c#

Tags: c#, jquery

Below is my jQuery code :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
<link href="Styles/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

        $("#btnprnt").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                No: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and this is my button click event :

```
protected void btnprnt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Response.Redirect("Print.aspx");

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType  (), "NewWindow", "function();", true);
}
```

My button is in ajax panel.
I am calling jquery function in code behind.
But this button click dosen't fire jquery.

Comment: If i get you right.Do you want to open a modal dialog box on click of button click?

Comment: ya, i want to open modal dialog box on click of button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this jquery plugin.
http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin